# Not able to get the last sequence ID inserted in DB using Spring's JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to insert a record in `Oracle` DB and get the sequence id (which is also the primary key for that table) for further use. I googled around SO links and found some code snippets and have been trying them but I am seeing following error while inserting record in Oracle DB.

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: The generated key is not of a supported numeric type. Unable to cast [oracle.sql.ROWID] to [java.lang.Number]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder.getKey(GeneratedKeyHolder.java:73)
    at com.ebayenterprise.publicapi.events.dao.DBConnectionUtils.insertEventLogData2(DBConnectionUtils.java:88)
    at com.ebayenterprise.publicapi.events.dao.DBConnectionUtils.main(DBConnectionUtils.java:42)
```

**Program Method**

```
 private static void insertEventLogData2() {
        //setup data
        EventType eventType = new EventType(EVENT_TYPE_ID, EVENT_TYPE_CD, null, null);
        Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(eventType, ROUTE_ID, ORDER_ID, null, null, currentTimestamp, currentTimestamp);
        System.out.println("eventLog = " + eventLog);

        //execute query
        GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_EVENT_LOG_MESSAGE_SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                statement.setInt(1, eventLog.getRouteId());
                statement.setInt(2, eventLog.getEventType().getEventTypeId());
                statement.setString(3, eventLog.getOrderId());
                statement.setTimestamp(4, eventLog.getIncomingEventTimestamp());
                statement.setTimestamp(5, eventLog.getOutgoingEventTimestamp());
                return statement;
            }
        }, holder);

        //get the sequence key
        long generatedEventId = holder.getKey().longValue();
        System.out.println("generatedEventId = " + generatedEventId);
    }
```

**Table Desc:**

```
EVENT_ID (Primary Key - Mapped to sequence EVENT_ID_SEQ)
ROUTE_ID
EVENT_TYPE_ID
ORDER_ID
INCOMING_EVENT_TIMESTAMP
OUTGOING_EVENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 3):

Never mind. Got it working through NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. Much cleaner implementation as well.

```
private static final String INSERT_EVENT_LOG_MESSAGE_SQL2 = "INSERT INTO "
        + "EVENT_LOG (EVENT_ID, ROUTE_ID, EVENT_TYPE_ID, ORDER_ID, INCOMING_EVENT_TIMESTAMP, OUTGOING_EVENT_TIMESTAMP) "
        + "VALUES (EVENT_LOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :routeId, :eventTypeId, :orderId, :incomingEventTS, :outgoingEventTS)";


private static void insertEventLogData() {
        //setup data
        EventType eventType = new EventType(EVENT_TYPE_ID, EVENT_TYPE_CD, null, null);
        Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(eventType, ROUTE_ID, ORDER_ID, null, null, currentTimestamp, currentTimestamp);
        System.out.println("eventLog = " + eventLog);

        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("routeId", ROUTE_ID);
        parameters.addValue("eventTypeId", EVENT_TYPE_ID);
        parameters.addValue("orderId", ORDER_ID);
        parameters.addValue("incomingEventTS", currentTimestamp);
        parameters.addValue("outgoingEventTS", currentTimestamp);

        GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        int nb = namedJdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_EVENT_LOG_MESSAGE_SQL2, parameters, holder, new String[]{"EVENT_ID"});

        //get the sequence key
        long generatedEventId = holder.getKey().longValue();
        System.out.println("generatedEventId = " + generatedEventId);
    }
```